# mysql getting difference of 2 result sets

Tags: mysql, dataset, relational-database, resultset, intersection

So I have two tables. One is called superIDs which has columns "superID BIGINT" and I have another one called mainIDs which has a column called "subid BIGINT". I know that mainIDS is a subset of superIDs. How can I see the rows that are ONLY in superID but not in mainIDs.

here is my attempt at a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM atlas_comparables.superIDs WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM atlas_comparables.mainIDs);
```

However, this is returning me an empty set. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM atlas_comparables.superIDs WHERE the_id_column NOT IN
    (SELECT the_idcolumn_ofcomparable FROM tlas_comparables.mainIDs);
```

Note: `the_id_column` is in `superIDs` table 
`the_idcolumn_ofcomparable` is in `MainIds`table

Comment: i think that atlas_comparables is a database, superIDs and mainIDs are two table names

Answer (score 0):

If the ids only appear (at most) once in each table, then you can do this relatively easily with a left outer join:

```
select si.*
from atlas_comparables.superIDs si left join
     atlas_comparables.mainIDs mi
     on si.SuperID = mi.SubID
where mi.SubId is NULL;
```

If you are trying to compare all the columns (as `except` does in other databases), then you need a more complicated query, where you include all the columns on the `on` clause.